# Wicket: Readable Links(Mounting) in TabbedPanel for Links in Tabs

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

how can i, in wicket, make for a tabbedpanel a link in a tab  readable  like "/subpath/tab1","subpath/tab2". Can i use MountablePageLink ?

?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the tail end of that URI be the PageParameter.  So that would be done in the Application class like:

```
mountPage("/subpath/${activeTag}", Foo.class);
```

which then you can set the active tab based on the PageParameter.  Then when you create the tabs you can set which one is the active one based on a default or the activeTag passed in.